# Netbeans endlessly "Background scanning of projects"

Tags: java, php, netbeans

There seem to be similar questions but not on the same versions.

Netbeans has been "Background scanning of projects..." for hours now (everything is newly installed) and I don't get anything in the predictive text nor Navigator. Both just show "Please Wait"

Is there something I can do here or is this a known issue?

```
OSX: 10.10.2
Netbeans: 8.0.2
Java: java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
Project Language: PHP
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to clear the Netbeans cache. It should (don't know the location in OSX) be located in

```
$your_user_directory/.netbeans/var/cache
```

To check if it might be related to some other settings try to start netbeans with a clear settings directory

```
netbeans --userdir <point_to_some_temporary_directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I didn't get anywhere. I've downgraded to 7.4 and it seems to be working alright.

Comment: Bad that nothing was working for you. From my point it can only be linked to some settings data.

Comment: Well, that's how it works sometimes. 10.10 is pretty new so I guess Netbeans just doesn't have the compatibility yet.